# Why does content disappear after switching between fragments in navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, navigation-drawer

I am using a navigation drawer and in one of my fragments, I have created a recycle view. But whenever I switch between fragments, the content for recycle view disappears .

This is

**mainactivity.java**

```
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.nav_image:

                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new ImagesFragment()).commit(); //this contains recycleview

                break;
            case R.id.nav_profile:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new ProfileFragment()).commit();
                break;

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);


        return true;
    }
```

**ImagesFragment.java**

```
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image,container,false);
     rv= (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.book_RV);

            //LAYOUT MANAGER
            rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
     GetImage();

    return rootView 

}
}
```

So my problem is whenever I switch between profile and images fragment, the content inside images disappears.

Comment: i managed to fix this i put the parts
           `View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image,container,false);
     rv= (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.book_RV);

            //LAYOUT MANAGER
            rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));` 
and the setadapter inside the `GetBook` method/Function

Answer (score 1):

Every time you are creating **new Fragment** instead of reusing old one.

You can create fragments as fields in your class:

```
ImagesFragment imagesFragment = new ImagesFragment();
ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
```

And inside your `switch` you can reuse them:

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.nav_image:
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        imagesFragment
                ).commit(); //this contains recycleview

        break;

    case R.id.nav_profile:
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        profileFragment)
                .commit();
        break;
}
```

**You can split your method to two:**

- first doing is selecting fragment
- second method is doing transactions.

Showing selected fragment (and hiding rest of them):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Create instance of the fragments
    ImagesFragment imagesFragment = new ImagesFragment();
    ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();

    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        // Select fragment to show
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_image:
                showFragment(imagesFragment);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_profile:
                showFragment(profileFragment);
                break;
        }

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    void showFragment(Fragment fragmentToShow) {
        // Create transactionns
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

        // Hide all of the fragments
        for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
            transaction.hide(fragment);
        }

        if (fragmentToShow.isAdded()) {
            // When fragment was previously added - show it
            transaction.show(fragmentToShow);
        } else {
            // When fragment is adding first time - add it
            transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentToShow);
        }

        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Boken said, I made a better approach:

Put this in onCreate method, below super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            showFragment(customFragment);
        }
```

Also delete any setHasFixedSize(), if there are.

Also declare the navigation listener inside the onCreate method.